# Crawling different Parents Tags but same Child Tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm crawling detail product pages in an online shop.
Each product has a chart that has different indexes.
for example,

product 1
brand : Nike
produced country : China

Product 2
brand : Adidas
price : $150

in this case, product 1 there is an index named 'produced country' but index 2 of product 2 is 'price'.
So It's confused that when I crawl this column name is 'Produced country' but in line 2 there is '$150'.

I wanna get all these information but have no idea to get 'country' and 'price' separately. I used try-except code but  is all same so even though I found 'rel' information, I couldn't get the next td's text next to td tag 'rel'.

## make 'tr's list

```
  B = A.findAll("tr")
  try:
    B.find("td",{"rel":"brand"})
    C = B.find("td",{"class":"last"})
  except:
    C= ""
  return C


 # Product 1
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td rel="brand">brand name</td>
   <td class="last">Nike</td>
  <tr>
   <td rel="country">country name</td>
   <td class="last">China</td>

 # Product 2
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td rel="brand">brand name</td>
     <td class="last">Adidas</td>
   <tr>
    <td rel="price">price</td>
    <td class="last">$150</td>
```

Comment: you could use `for row in B:` to work with every row separatelly and then you can find all `td` in row `tds = row.find_all("td")` and then in second row you will have `tds[0].text` is `price` or `country name`, and `tds[1].text` is `$150` or `China`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `for` loop to work with every `row` (every `tr`) separatelly and get all `td` in `row` and get `text` from every `td`. This way you work with every row separatelly and you can keep it in dictionary or in other structure.

```
data = '''<table>
<tr>
   <td rel="brand">brand name</td>
   <td class="last">Nike</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td rel="country">country name</td>
   <td class="last">China</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
     <td rel="brand">brand name</td>
     <td class="last">Adidas</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rel="price">price</td>
    <td class="last">$150</td>
</tr>
</table>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

results = []

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    item = dict()

    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        tds = row.find_all('td')
        key = tds[0].text
        value = tds[1].text
        item[key] = value

    results.append(item)    

print(results)
```

Result:

```
[
  {'brand name': 'Nike', 'country name': 'China'}, 
  {'brand name': 'Adidas', 'price': '$150'}
]
```